# Get-sentiment Powershell

Tags: powershell, sentiment-analysis

How would I go about getting the score decimal returns into just returning the scores as a Percentage?[Current powershell line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXOKr.png)

```
 Get-Sentiment -Text "Im angry", "Hey good morning!" | ForEach-Object documents
```

Returns

```
id               score
--               -----
1  0.00449720025062561
2  0.98748815059661865
```

Any Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the string tokenization and filtering:

```
"{0:P2}" -f $SomeVariableContainingANumberToConvertToPercentage
```

Where '0' is the index for the first token, 'P' is telling PowerShell to format it as a 'percentage' and '2' is telling it to limit the conversion to two places (e.g. 95.22%)

Edit:

Based on your edit with the Return data, you'd want to format the returned object's 'Score' property.

```
$data = "id,score
1,0.00449720025062561
2,0.98748815059661865
" | ConvertFrom-Csv


$data | Select-Object id,@{n='ScoreFormatted'; e={ ("{0:P2}" -f [float]$_.Score) }}
```

Outputs:

```
id ScoreFormatted
-- --------------
1  0.45%         
2  98.75%
```

Comment: OK, that helps.  I'd like to figure out how to make this dynamic though from the beginning.  If different strings produce different decimal returns, to be efficient, it would have to be dynamic..

Comment: Look at each value passed, enum the number of digits, and take action on that.